# New-WebServiceProxy fails

Tags: powershell, wcf

I'm trying to use the PowerShell command New-WebServiceProxy to create a connection to a WCF Service.

I've got the WCF Services up and running (and working from C# code), but the following PowerShell code fails:

```
PS C:\>$uri = "http://localhost/Person.svc?wsdl"
PS C:\>$client = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri

New-WebServiceProxy : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
At line:1 char:30
+ $client = New-WebServiceProxy <<<<  -Uri $uri
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-WebServiceProxy], TargetInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
```

What could be the problem here?

Edit; Don't know if it is relevant, but the Services uses some custom SOAP headers for credentials.

Comment: Can you open Visual Studio, add a new C# project and Add Service Reference to the URL listed?  Make sure you haven't loaded the solution that implements the service.  Just trying to see if the problem is with PowerShell or the service.

Comment: If you try "http://localhost/Person.svc?wsdl" in a browser does it appear to work?

Comment: Yes, it works from C#. So the problem is pure PowerShell related.

Comment: It would be useful to see the actual exception thrown via $Error[0].Exception.InnerException and .StackTrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing the `svcutil.exe` utility from the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) with the `/validate` parameter.  Look at the utilities usage for details on the parameter usage for `/validate`.  Note that in a pinch you can just use svcutil.exe to create the proxy class which you would then compile.  Back in the day before PowerShell 2.0 and New-WebProxy, this is [how we created web service proxies](http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!645.entry).

Comment: How can I use the /validate when all I have is a URL to the WCF service?

Comment: I used WSDL to generate C# proxy class, is there a way for PowerShell to compile and use this as a DLL instead?

Comment: Look at the `Add-Type` command's help.  You can compile C# source (to a dynamic assembly) and use that from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [script version of New-WebServiceProxy](http://poshcode.org/1340), which is based on wsdl.exe

Comment: Hi, when running the script I get this error: WARNING: c:\Users\frodel\AppData\Local\Temp\bgd3k_a2.0.cs(100,30) : warning CS0108:
'service1.WcfPersonService.Credentials' hides inherited member
'System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.Credentials'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: That's really funky: your web service defines a Credentials property that gets in the way of web service client implementations ... That's going to cause pain for anyone implementing it I think. However, a compile WARNING should be ok, unless it's treating the warning as an error...

Answer (score 1):

What WCF bindings are you using?

By default a WCF project using the wsHttpBinding, which assumes the client will support more WS-* features than available in the proxy created by powershell's new-webserviceproxy cmdlet.

Change the (or create a new) endpoint binding that uses basicHttpBinding, and ensure that HTTP GET is supported for metadata; e.g.,:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I have that enabled - still not luck.